# What is wrong with this stored procedure

Tags: database, stored-procedures, db2

What is wrong with this stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_RESULT_SET ()
LANGUAGE SQL
RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN
  DECLARE MYCUR CURSOR WITH RETURN  FOR
     SELECT USERNAME , NAME FROM SLPG.USER ORDER BY ID;
  OPEN MYCUR;
END;
```

I get error like

DB2 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows: "END" was expected to form a complete scope.  -- near BEGIN statement

DB2 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows: "" was expected to form a complete scope. -- near DECLARE statement

DB2 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows: " JOIN " was expected to form a complete scope. -- near OPEN statement

DB2 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows: Unexpected text "END" encountered. -- near END statement

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a different terminator for the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement itself, as the semicolon is used to terminate statements within the procedure body.