# DB2 sql Query Syntax error

Tags: sql, db2

I was practicing this query from [Query Site](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008328.html)

```
create procedure median_result_set(out mediansalary decimal(5,2))
result sets 1 
language sql
begin
   declare v_numrowrecords int default 1;

declare v_counter int default 0;

declare c1 cursor for 
     select salary from 
     staff 
     order by salary;

declare c2 cursor with return for 
    select name ,job, cast(salary as integer)
    from staff
    where salary > mediansalary
    order by salary;

declare exit handler for not found 
    set mediansalary=6666;

set mediansalary=0;

SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO v_numrowrecords
  FROM ASFAKUL.STAFF;

open c1;

while v_counter < (v_numrowrecords/2+1) 
     do 
       fetch c1 into mediansalary;

set v_counter=v_counter+1;

end while;

close c1;

open c2;

end;
```

but I am getting syntax error in DB2 10.5 . I dont have any idea why I am getting error. please help . Also please explain how we are getting the **mediansalary** as input in the second cursor . in oracle we could just declare the input as part of the cursor declaration but we have done nothing that sort over here .  can somebody please explain. I am using SAMPLE schema.here is all the info

**Product name:                     "DB2 Express-C"

License type:                     "Unwarranted"

Expiry date:                      "Permanent"

Product identifier:               "db2expc"

Version information:              "10.5"

Max number of CPUs:               "2"

Max amount of memory (GB):        "16"

Enforcement policy:               "Soft Stop"**

Comment: Seems a licensing issue.

Comment: How could that be? It doesn't accept syntax because of license!

Comment: Search more about that soft stop thing,its just a wild guess.Seems i was way off.http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.license.doc/license/tlicpol.htm

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266700/an-unexpected-token-create-trigger

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20876637/what-is-wrong-with-this-stored-procedure

Comment: Having a "special" (especially _positive_!) value for the not-found condition is trouble - what happens if the actual median salary is `6666`?  The value chosen won't fit - largest value posssible is `999.99` (first number is _total_ digits).  Using two cursors this way is going to make this _ridiculously_ slow - and unless you lock the table, you're not guaranteed the correct results anyways.  Since you're on a recent DB2 LUW, [you can do this in one statement](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/how_to_do_median_in_db253?lang=en)