# Getting error while executing Plsql function

Tags: sql, db2

I'm getting error while executing below mentioned query in DB2.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ETLUAT.FUNC_GET_CLAIM_STATUS(IN i_claim_no Varchar(4000))
RETURNS varchar(4000)
BEGIN
  DECLARE tempReasonid  varchar(50);
  DECLARE tempReasontxt varchar(5000);
  DECLARE txtreason     varchar(4000);
  DECLARE tempStatus        varchar(1);
  DECLARE tempUpdateNo      int;
  DECLARE tempOutPut        varchar(2000); 
  DECLARE tempCnt           int;
  DECLARE tempPayStatus     int;
  DECLARE tempPayStatusChar varchar(25);
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN
   RETURN 'OTHERS';
  END;
  Select A.TXT_CLAIM_STATUS, a.num_update_no into tempStatus, tempUpdateNo From ETLUAT.PRESTG_GC_CLAIM_INFO A
  where A.Num_Update_No =(Select Max(Num_Update_No) From ETLUAT.PRESTG_GC_CLAIM_INFO G Where G.Num_Claim_No = i_claim_no) and a.num_claim_no = i_claim_no;
  if tempStatus = 'N' then SET tempOutPut = 'Notification';
  elseif tempStatus = 'I' then
            begin
                select count(1) into tempCnt from ETLUAT.PRESTG_GC_CLAIM_INFO where TXT_CLAIM_STATUS = 'I'
                AND NUM_CLAIM_NO = i_claim_no and NUM_UPDATE_NO >(select max(NUM_UPDATE_NO) From ETLUAT.PRESTG_GC_CLAIM_INFO
                where TXT_CLAIM_STATUS = 'N' AND NUM_CLAIM_NO = i_claim_no);
                    if tempCnt = 1 then SET tempOutPut = 'Registration';
                        elseif tempCnt > 1 then SET tempOutPut = 'Processing';
                            else SET tempOutPut = 'Others';
                    end if;
                return tempOutPut;
            END;
  end if;
    return tempOutPut;
END;
```

error:SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "END".  Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN <joined_table>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.9.78

please anyone help me to figure out my mistake.

Comment: What tool do you use to run this statement? You must change the default statement terminator / delimiter (;) used in this tool to, say, `@`, to run this statement like this: `CREATE FUNCTION ... BEGIN stmt1; ... stmtN; END@`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is wrong with this stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20876637/what-is-wrong-with-this-stored-procedure)

Comment: Hi Mark we are using db2. still i'm getting same error

Comment: Please, provide a link with a fully reproducible example showin a error like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/6pjm1B_y) one.